# Append the value to duplicate hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I wanted to create a hash that would be append the email with name if that name exist in someother hash. I believe there would be small piece of code that will do the ruby magic.

```
Input

a = [
  {"email"=>"foobar@gmail.com", "name"=>"Adam"}, 
  {"email"=>"test@gmail.com",   "name"=>"John"}, 
  {"email"=>"hello@gmail.com",  "name"=>"Adam"}
]



Output
a = [
  {"email"=>"foobar@gmail.com", "name"=>"Adam | foobar@gmail.com"}, 
  {"email"=>"test@gmail.com",   "name"=>"John"}, 
  {"email"=>"hello@gmail.com",  "name"=>"Adam | hello@gmail.com "}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
# get names
names = a.map {|e| e['name'] }
# find duplicates
duplicates  = names.detect {|e| names.count(e) > 1 }
# append email to duplicates
a.each { |e| e['name'] = "#{e['name']} | #{e['email']}" if duplicate.include?(e['name'])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your input

```
a = [
  {"email"=>"foobar@gmail.com", "name"=>"Adam"}, 
  {"email"=>"test@gmail.com",   "name"=>"John"}, 
  {"email"=>"hello@gmail.com",  "name"=>"Adam"}
]
```

And I'll provide a cleverly named comparison hash of my own

```
b = [
  {"name"=>"Adam"},
  {"name"=>"Adam"}
]
```

Here's your ruby magic

```
a.map do |hash_a|
  # This is the 'magic' line that compares the values of
  # the two hashes name values
  if b.any? { |hash_b| hash_b['name'] == hash_a['name'] }
    hash_a['name'] << " | #{hash_a['email']}"
    hash_a
  else
    hash_a
  end
end
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "email" => "foobar@gmail.com",
     "name" => "Adam | foobar@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "email" => "test@gmail.com",
     "name" => "John"
  },
  {
    "email" => "hello@gmail.com",
     "name" => "Adam | hello@gmail.com"
  }
]
```